# How to increase the size of the title bar in an Android application?

Tags: android

How to increase the size of the title bar attached to the top of any screen in android

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is android title bar and you can not increase its size. It you need this feature in your application then you can create a custom title bar.

Remove the this default Title bar by using this code in your activity..

```
getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

or this in your manifast inside your activity tag.

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

and then create a custom title bar in your XML file.

Comment: it's not true ... this answer is wrong ... disabling title bar and making own in activity layout it's not a real solution

Comment: @Sujit I guess that Selvin would like had say that the preffered approach is make your own _Title Bar Customized_. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27916832/3072683)

Answer (score 28):

> EDIT:

this solution was for API < 11 ... now we have ActionBars

> EDIT: first i answer this

[Create custom titlebar in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753223/make-custom-titlebar-in-android)

> EDIT: I'm adding this because I think Sujit gave the wrong answer.

To increase the size of the title bar you will need to add file with this content to `res/values`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme">
        <item name="android:windowTitleSize">50dip</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
        <activity android:theme="@style/CustomTheme" android:name=".Activity" android:label="AppName">
...
        </activity>
```

Comment: Have you gone through the link that you have mention here?? If yes then this is what i have also written that you have to create your custom title bar. First try to read whatever are copying and pasting....

Comment: yes i did ... **you wrote** how to build "custom bar" by dissabling real one and **make a fake one** in Layout ... **this link provide information how to build real custom bar in "android way"**

Comment: yes but the only difference is that it has requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE); instead of getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)

Comment: no ... this is not only difference ... it's about reusing the code like here http://selvinlistsyncsample.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/824065689cc2#src%2fselvin%2fListSyncSample%2fCustomWindow.java i build CustomWindow and few of my activities are using this class as a base ... so in this activities i have the same title bar without adding it to layout ... i asume that you don't know what are design patterns and you build all your code adhoc ... it's leading to buggy, not reusable code

Comment: @Selvin Ok what so special about your this CustomWindow, what if I create a base Activity using Sujit procedure and extend all activities of my app with that base activity is not that code reusability, then I must say you should write a book on design pattern, its easy to critic on one rather than admiring

Comment: hehe good one first you vote -1 for comments not for answer(which is correct) ... second with Suijit code in base Activity ... well you will have Activity without TitleBar ... nothing more ... you still need to add "title bar" in every layout ... i know that thinking sometimes hurt ... but come on :)

Comment: ROFL man your answer is correct and Sujit's is also correct but the way you criticize is wrong also there are many ways to do the same thing, its just matter of choice, and as U said thinking hurts I suggest you to implement and try my way and then tell whether you see the title in all activities or not, Its not better to always think rather trying things helps alot in understanding them

Comment: "This is android title bar and you can not increase its size." <= yeah sure this is correct answer :)

Comment: Ok, whats the diff between in built API and overriding :P

Comment: Eh... this answer is the RIGHT one. The one before this was kinda useless to me... Upgrade this one please folks. It's actually helpful.

Comment: Funny.. I encountered the same problem almost a year later, and read the above answer and kept scratching my head. Came to this one and again, got the job done. This answer is the best.