# Android: Increase title bar size?

Tags: android, android-layout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to increase the size of the title bar in an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226538/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-title-bar-in-an-android-application)

How can I increase the size of the title bar in Android?

I created a custom layout R.layout.mytitle and onCreate() I call:

getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.mytitle);

but in my layout, no matter what height I use, it seems to ignore it, and uses a default height.

How can I change this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226538/how-to-increase-the-size-of-the-title-bar-in-an-android-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change anything on the title bar basically.

Check [this](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/) out.

A nice supplement to the comments given already.

Comment: The link is broken