# Can't get back the screen size android

Tags: android, size, height, width

I've a little problem, as show in this pictures, i can't bring back the screen size as i want, and i'm a little lost...
(I'm learning)

http://imageshack.us/f/708/erreurtaillepong4.png/

http://imageshack.us/f/708/erreurtaillepong5.png/

I need to have the width and height of the screen

Please help

EDIT 1

Here's my code as asked :

```
package com.salocincreations.pong;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;

public class GameState {

    //Largeur et hauteur de l'écran
    int _screenWidth = TailleEcran.Measuredwidth;
    int _screenHeight = TailleEcran.Measuredheight;


    //La balle
    final int _ballSize = 10;
    int _ballX = _screenWidth/2;    int _ballY = _screenHeight/2;
    int _ballVelocityX = 2;     int _ballVelocityY = 4;

    //Les barres
    final int _batLength = 75;  final int _batHeight = 10;
    int _topBatX = (_screenWidth/2) - (_batLength / 2);
    final int _topBatY = 10;
    int _bottomBatX = (_screenWidth/2) - (_batLength / 2);  
    final int _bottomBatY = _screenHeight - 20;

    public GameState()
    {
    }

    //The update method
    public void update() {

    _ballX += _ballVelocityX;
    _ballY += _ballVelocityY;

    //DEATH!
    if(_ballY > _bottomBatY + 10 || _ballY < 0)         
    {_ballX = 100;  _ballY = 100;}//Collisions with the goals

    if(_ballX > _screenWidth || _ballX < 0)
                _ballVelocityX *= -1;   //Collisions with the sides     

    if(_ballX > _topBatX && _ballX < _topBatX+_batLength && _ballY - 16 < _topBatY)         
                     _ballVelocityY *= -1;  //Collisions with the bats      

    if(_ballX > _bottomBatX && _ballX < _bottomBatX+_batLength 
                    && _ballY + 16 > _bottomBatY)
                           _ballVelocityY *= -1;
    }

    public boolean surfaceTouched(float posX, float posY) {
        _topBatX = (int) posX;
        _bottomBatX = (int) posX;

        return true;
        }


    //the draw method
    public void draw(Canvas canvas, Paint paint) {

    //Clear the screen
    canvas.drawRGB(0, 0, 0);

    //set the colour
    paint.setARGB(200, 0, 200, 700);

    //draw the ball
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(_ballX,_ballY,_ballX + _ballSize,_ballY + _ballSize),
                                 paint);

    //draw the bats
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(_topBatX, _topBatY, _topBatX + _batLength,
                                          _topBatY + _batHeight), paint); //top bat
    canvas.drawRect(new Rect(_bottomBatX, _bottomBatY, _bottomBatX + _batLength, 
                                          _bottomBatY + _batHeight), paint); //bottom bat

        // Nous allons dessiner nos points par rapport à la résolution de l'écran
        int iWidth = canvas.getWidth(); // Largeur
        int iHeight = canvas.getHeight(); // Hauteur

        // Affecter une couleur de manière aléatoire
            paint.setARGB(255, 500, 500, 500);
            // Définir l'épaisseur du segment
            paint.setStrokeWidth (2);
            // Puis dessiner nos points dans le cavenas
            canvas.drawLine(0, iHeight/2, iWidth, iHeight/2, paint);    
            canvas.drawCircle(iWidth/2, iHeight/2, 50, paint);
        }            
    }
```

and

```
public class TailleEcran extends Activity {


    int Measuredwidth;
    int Measuredheight;
    Point size = new Point();
    WindowManager w = getWindowManager();{

      if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2){
            w.getDefaultDisplay().getSize(size);

            Measuredwidth = size.x;
            Measuredheight = size.y; 
          }else{
            Display d = w.getDefaultDisplay(); 
            Measuredwidth = d.getWidth(); 
            Measuredheight = d.getHeight(); 
          }}}
```

At lines

```
int _screenWidth = TailleEcran.Measuredwidth;
int _screenHeight = TailleEcran.Measuredheight;
```

the errors says : Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field TailleEcran.Measuredwidth

and

Cannot make a static reference to the non-static field TailleEcran.Measuredheight

EDIT 2

Then, anthropomo, i need to write ?

```
        public class GameState {
        // declare variables above here without assignments
        Display display = ((WindowManager)
            context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(metrics);

        int pixHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
        int pixWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    // dp numbers:
        float density  = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float dpHeight = pixHeight / density;
        float dpWidth  = pixWidth / density;
public GameState(Context context){
//all the rest of my class
    }

}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15366712/size-of-the-usable-screen/15367869#15367869 for a standard way to know the size of your view.

Comment: Rather than screenshots, you should cut and paste relevant sections of code into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
Point size = new Point();
display.getSize(size);
int width = size.x;
int height = size.y;
```

On API before 13 you can use:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
```

Comment: Look at my second link, i'ts already in another class, but i think it returns 0

Comment: @NicMer please paste your code in your question I'll try to debug it.

Comment: @NicMer please post it all the code, because I am getting no errors

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Context.getResources()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29) and [Resources.getDisplayMetrics](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getDisplayMetrics%28%29) like this:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
```

Then you'll have

```
displayMetrics.widthPixels;  // width
displayMetrics.heightPixels; // height
```

Comment: My class must extends what for this ?  When i put "extends Activity", i have multi errors look http://imageshack.us/f/547/erreurtaillepong7.png/

Answer (score 0):

For compatibility in <13 and non-deprecated:

```
    Display display = ((WindowManager)
        context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);

    int pixHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
    int pixWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
// dp numbers:
    float density  = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dpHeight = pixHeight / density;
    float dpWidth  = pixWidth / density;
```

Edit:

You are getting errors on `display.getMetrics(metrics);` because only declarations can take place outside of methods in a class.  All of this code should be in a method, and assuming GameState is not really an Activity, this stuff should be in the constructor.  Something like this:

```
public class GameState {
    // declare variables above here without assignments

    public GameState(Context context){
        // everything above, but save the variables outside of the constructor
    }

}
```

Then in the Activity that uses GameState, do `gameState = new GameState(this);`

Comment: I have too many errors :  "context cannot be resolved" and look http://imageshack.us/f/854/erreurtaillepong8.png/

Comment: context in this case would be `this` if it's in your activity.

Comment: Ok, the context error diseappeared but there is still the errors at  display.getMetrics(metrics);

Comment: Sorry i'm french so i don't understand all... Look at the edit